# How to get the specific foreground window of the application

Tags: windows, winapi

Can I somehow get the specific foreground window of the application? For example, not the `HWND` of the whole Skype application, but some currently selected internal window of this application (maybe it's chat window's text edit).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [GetActiveWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292.aspx). Note, that each thread (or group of input-attached threads) has an active window, so an application can have multiple active windows concurrently.

Comment: Wouldn't that return the top-level active window for the current application? He wants to access the currently focused window of any application... would `GUITHREADINFO.hwndFocus` be the answer then? Or does @FrozenHeart want to do something that would be better suited to automation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EnumChildWindows.

Basically, it goes through the child windows of a given window until you find the one that has the characteristics you want. And - it is good to know that the "parent" of all application windows is HWND_DESKTOP

Here is code:

```
EnumChildWindows(HWND_PARENT,findChildWithClass,(LPARAM)"NetUIHWND");
```

And somewhere else:

```
   BOOL CALLBACK findChildWithClass(HWND hwndTest,LPARAM lParam) {
   char *pszClass = (char *)lParam;
   char szClass[64];
   GetClassName(hwndTest,szClass,64);
   if ( strlen(szClass) < 1 ) return TRUE;
   if ( 0 == _strnicmp(pszClass,szClass,min(strlen(pszClass),strlen(szClass))) ) {
       hwndFoundChild = hwndTest;
       return FALSE;
   }
   EnumChildWindows(hwndTest,findChildWithClass,lParam);
   if ( hwndFoundChild )
      return FALSE;
   return TRUE;
   }
```

So, the function "findChildWithClass" will be repeatedly called by Windows with the handle to the next child of the specified parent.
When the characteristics of that child window match what you are looking for, in this case class name, the function sets the value of a global static and returns FALSE to indicate the enumeration should stop.

You can get the class name of any window using Spy++, in this case, I used spy++ to find the name of the MS Word frame window. However, since the particular code will also look at every child of every child sent to it - you could have also found an "inner" window of MS Word using it. Also - you don't have to use class name, perhaps something else (window contents ?) is unique to the application you are trying to discover the window for ( Skype ? )

Comment: *It is good to know that the "parent" of all application windows is HWND_DESKTOP*. Except that's not true. Top level windows don't have parents. And typically they don't have owners either.

Comment: In point of fact, HWND_DESKTOP is 0 - and using EnumChildWindows with this value does indeed find all top level windows.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was confused. I assumed `HWND_DESKTOP` would be an actual window but that is no so. FWIW I think the asker wants to know something other than can be found in your answer. However, I don't think the question is clear. Looking at askers other question I think asker wants to know which window will receive input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067103/how-to-capture-any-specific-key-pressing-from-all-running-applications-in-window

Comment: EnumChildWindows accepts `NULL` for `hWndParent` as a special case to mean "enumerate top-level windows".  The fact that `NULL` is numerically equal to `HWND_DESKTOP` is just a coincidence, it doesn't mean that the desktop is *actually* the parent of all top-level windows.